# Add auth to many to many Amplify GraphQL DataStore connection

Tags: graphql, authorization, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am beginning a project with Amplify DataStore and modeling data that has a many-to-many relationship that also requires authorization. I'm having a hard time finding examples of M2M *with auth*, there are none in the documentation.

Here is a [MTM example from the DataStore docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/relational/q/platform/js#many-to-many), I want to prevent users that are not PostEditors from being able to load Posts. Currently the plan is to use Cognito, but open to other solutions. How would this be achieved?

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  editors: [PostEditor] @connection(keyName: "byPost", fields: ["id"])
}

type PostEditor
  @model(queries: null)
  @key(name: "byPost", fields: ["postID", "editorID"])
  @key(name: "byEditor", fields: ["editorID", "postID"]) {
  id: ID!
  postID: ID!
  editorID: ID!
  post: Post! @connection(fields: ["postID"])
  editor: User! @connection(fields: ["editorID"])
}

type User @model {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  posts: [PostEditor] @connection(keyName: "byEditor", fields: ["id"])
}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Vingtoft It's been a while, but I believe there is no solution with DataStore. The only option was to use the Amplify GraphQL API in the app and write your own GraphQL resolver on the backend. Additionally, this meant you would need to deal with data coming from two APIs. I ended up not working on that project anymore but I believe they moved to Firestore. Writing authorization is cumbersome, but doable.

Comment: Thank you @callmetwan. Feel free to post your comment as an answer, then I will award you the bounty. Thanks.